# Segmentation Fault when using "mov" in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I am working on a simple assembly program for a class, and am encountering an odd segmentation fault.  It's a pretty simple program to convert bytes into kilobytes.  However, within the function that does the conversion, I get a segmentation fault when I try to move the value 1024 into the `ebx` register.  I've never had this kind of problem before when working with registers.  Does someone know what could be causing this?  I imagine it is something simple that I'm overlooking.  Thank you!

```
asm_main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha

    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    call read_int
    push eax
    call functionA

    popa
    mov
    leave
    ret
functionA:
    mov eax, [esp + 4]
    call print_int
    call print_nl
    mov ebx, 1024 ;segmentation fault occurs here
    div ebx
    call print_int
    ret
```

UPDATE: One interesting discovery is that if I delete the lines interacting with the stack, `push eax` and `mov eax, [esp + 4]`, there is no longer a segmentation fault.  However, I get a crazy result in `eax` after performing `div ebx`.

Comment: I'm about 94% certain it doesn't *occur* there; that's just where EIP is pointing, which typically indicates that the fault happened on the instruction right before.

Comment: I would suspect that either `print_int` or `print_nl` is where your problem lies.  Can you add the source for them?

Comment: The functions for `print_int` and `print_nl` are included in an include line at the beginning of the program, as part of a template provided by the instructor, so I do not have the source for them.

Comment: One interesting discovery is that if I delete the lines interacting with the stack, `push eax` and `mov eax, [esp + 4]`, there is no longer a segmentation fault.  However, I get a crazy result in eax after performing `div ebx`.  I'll update the original post to reflect this information.

Comment: Moving an immediate value into a general-purpose register cannot cause a processor exception. I believe @cHao is on the right track.  I think your instructor's code is less-than-bulletproof, and your code is causing a bug in his to manifest itself.

Comment: What's up with the lone `mov` instruction after the `popa`?

Comment: How do those two provided functions expect to be called? How many arguments does it take? What does it return? Calling convention used?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - The `mov` instruction is included as part of the template I was provided, so I'm actually not entirely sure what it's purpose is

Comment: @quithakay207 And yet the code assembles just fine with it in there? A `mov` with no operands is not valid assembly code.

Comment: @greatwolf - The `print_int` function prints the value that is currently stored in eax and `'print_nl` prints a new line.  They don't take any arguments, and they are just called as they are in my code.  I've used them before without such issues.  I tried deleting those lines, just in case, and the segmentation fault still occurred.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - The code assembles and runs with that `mov` at the end.  I've used the same template for a few assignments and it hasn't been an issue before.

Comment: What about `readint`?

Comment: @greatwolf - `readint` reads an integer value from the user and stores it in `eax`.

Comment: So you're saying `mov eax, [esp + 4]` followed with `mov ebx, 1024` will *still* segfault? That doesn't sound possible unless the stackpointer is foobar'ed somehow pointing to somewhere it shouldn't

Comment: Yeah, it goes away if I delete the `push eax` and `mov eax, [esp + 4]` lines and just store the value in `eax`. However, for the assignment, we need to use the stack so I can't work around it.  Not sure if this is related, but when I input 2000 into `eax` and divide it by the 1024 value in `ebx`, I should get a quotient of 1, but instead I get 4194305.  Oddly enough, the correct remainder of 976 is stored in `edx`.

Comment: I suspect there is something going on with `readint`. What happens when you comment out 3 lines above `push eax` and just load eax with an instance of valid input just before the `push`? eg. `mov eax, 2048`?

Comment: Good Lord, People!!! This is the most common newbie error in the entire world! Look up what `div` divides by what. We may "want" a 32-bit by 32-bit division, but there's no such instruction. `div` (with a 32-bit operand) divides 64 bits (edx:eax) by what you say, and puts the quotient in eax. If the result won't fit in eax (exceeds 32 bits), go boom! Put `xor edx, edx` (or, if you must, `mov edx, 0`) right before the `div`, and your problem will vanish. (Dr. Carter's code is available if you want to look at it, but it is not the problem).

Comment: @FrankKotler: a non-zero value in EDX will produce an inaccurate result, but it won't cause a fault.  (Of course, a fault might happen if you don't know that `div` modifies EDX, and had a pointer stored there that you subsequently tried to use...but the code here isn't showing any signs of that.)

Comment: @cHao - You wanna bet? Try `div edx`.

Comment: @FrankKotler: Again, that's not happening here.  EDX is never used directly by this code...not as a pointer, index, or even a remainder.

Comment: @cHao - suit yourself.

Comment: `EDX` IS being directly used in this code, even if you don't see it!!!  `div` uses edx:eax, if you don't zero out edx before the div, there can be any number in edx.

Comment: @Gunner: And the resulting error, if it occurs, would be a #DE -- not a segfault.

Comment: @cHao At this point I'm not sure we can fully trust what the OP is saying -- he may not be able to distinguish the difference between the different exceptions generated.

Comment: @greatwolf: You might be right about that.  Most people don't just pull the words "segmentation fault" out of thin air, though.  I would hope the OS at least is giving him accurate info.

Comment: @FrankKotler - Thank you for the suggestion!  While that did not solve the segmentation fault, it did stop my quotient from exploding
And the suggestion that functions such as `read_int` and `print_int` were causing issues seems to be correct.  Pushing `eax` and using those functions seemed to mess up `eax` so I stored the user's value in `ecx`, pushed that, and the segmentation fault went away.  I don't really want to answer my own question, since the answer came from suggestions you all provided.  If someone wants the credit, go for it.  Otherwise, thank you everyone!

Comment: Also, how do I vote up helpful comments?  Or do I need more reputation for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enough comments! My apologies to cHao, the bad `div` will cause an exception, not a segfault. As greatwolf says, the stack pointer is foobar'ed... by pushing the parameter to `functionA` and not removing it. I missed that on my first read-through.

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
asm_main:
enter 0,0
pusha

mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
call read_int
push eax
call functionA
add esp, 4 ; or pop something to remove the parameter
popa
mov eax, 0 ; to return a value to "driver.c"
leave
ret
functionA:
mov eax, [esp + 4]
call print_int
call print_nl
mov ebx, 1024 ;segmentation fault occurs here (??? I doubt it)
xor edx, edx ; "div" is going to use this!
div ebx
call print_int
ret
```

That's untested, but I "think" it's okay. The code for `read_int` etc. can be found at http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm - it just uses scanf (and printf, etc) to smooth out the differences between OSen. I think it's fine.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  And thanks to everyone else how helped me!